# How to split list into disjoint lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, intersection

I wonder if there is any simple way to split a list into its disjoint sublists, e.g. from

```
list={{a,b},{e,f},{b,c},{c,d},{f,g,h}}
```

get a result

```
listdis={{{a,b},{b,c},{c,d}},{{e,f},{f,g,h}}},
```

so that one gets disjoint sublists such that any element can be connected with another element through other elements inside that list (like a disjoint chains of elements).

Obviously sublists are of any length.

Answer (score 14):

This is a standard connectivity problem. Here is a graph-based solution:

```
ClearAll[listToGraph];
listToGraph[list_List]:=
   Graph @ Union[
         Sort /@ Flatten[Apply[UndirectedEdge,(Partition[#1,2,1]&) /@ list,{2}]]
   ];


ClearAll[getConnectivityRules];
getConnectivityRules[graph_Graph]:=
   (Dispatch[Flatten[Thread /@ Thread[#1 -> Range[Length[#1]]]]]&)[
      ConnectedComponents[graph]
   ];


ClearAll[connectedComponents];
connectedComponents[list_List]:=
   With[{connectivityRules = getConnectivityRules @ listToGraph @ list},
      GatherBy[list,First[#1] /. connectivityRules&]
   ]
```

so that

```
connectedComponents[list]

(* {{{a, b}, {b, c}, {c, d}}, {{e, f}, {f, g, h}}}  *)
```

Comment: This one needs a bit of improvement (Union[Sort/@edgelist]) to handle lists like this: `list = {{a, b}, {b, a}, {c, d}}`.

Comment: This looks like a very good idea, to construct the graph over the sublist elements, and avoid having to do pairwise tests over sublists.  I wonder what is the theoretically most efficient way for various kinds of inputs.

Comment: @Szabolcs Re: improvement - thanks, nicely spotted. Done now. Re: most efficient way - this problem is discussed e.g. in the book of Robert Sedgewick, "Algorithms in C", I think, at the very start. He gives several algorithms, such as union-find algorithm (fast union of fast find). This can be a good place to start if you are interested, it is nicely explained there.

Comment: @Szabolcs Actually, my translation of one of the algorithms from Sedgewick's book into Mathematica can be found in [this thread](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Nov/msg00279.html), in which you did also participate, and from which Ray adopted Carl's answer, which he posted here. This was actually that historical thread, where the solution based on recursive pure functions was also developed. My fastest version there was in [this post](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Nov/msg00321.html).

Answer (score 9):

Another graph-based solution:

```
Sort@Cases[#, _List] & /@ ConnectedComponents@
  Graph@Flatten[Thread@UndirectedEdge[ConstantArray[#, Length[#]], #] & /@ list]
```

> ```
> {{{a, b}, {b, c}, {c, d}}, {{e, f}, {f, g, h}}}
> ```

Here I construct the following graph

```
Graph[Thread@UndirectedEdge[ConstantArray[#, Length[#]], #] & /@ 
   list // Flatten, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Then I find connected components and choose vertices with `List` head.

Comment: This one fails on `list = RandomInteger[100, {100, 10}]` due to multiple edges.

Comment: @Szabolcs Good catch! One can add `DeleteDuplicates` but it is not very good.

Answer (score 7):

This is the same graph-based idea that other solution use, with a slightly shorter, and (to me) more intuitive implementation.  Let's first make an adjacency matrix based on sublist intersections:

```
graph = AdjacencyGraph@Unitize@Outer[Composition[Length, Intersection], list, list, 1];

list[[#]] & /@ ConnectedComponents[graph]

(* ==> {{{a, b}, {b, c}, {c, d}}, {{e, f}, {f, g, h}}} *)
```

Comment: You can specify vertex list when you construct adjacency graph: AdjacencyGraph[list, 
 Sign@Outer[Composition[Length, Intersection], list, list, 1]]

Answer (score 7):

This is an adaptation of Carl Woll's [`aggs`](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Nov/msg00320.html). It's less obvious but may be substantially faster for long lists. "cis" stands for "collect intersecting sublists".

```
cis[list_] := Module[{j,aj}, list[[#]]& /@
  SparseArray`StronglyConnectedComponents[ Sign[#.Transpose@# &
  @ SparseArray @ Thread[ Join@@( Function[{j,aj}, {j,#}& /@ Union@aj]
  @@@ Transpose@{Range@Length@list, list /. Thread[
  # -> Range@Length@#]& @ Union@Flatten@list} ) -> 1 ]]]]

cis[list]

(* {{{a,b},{b,c},{c,d}},{{e,f},{f,g,h}}} *)
```

Comment: +1. I actually published the `Compile`-based implementation on Mathgroup a while ago, which was beating Carl's code (although not by much), but it is much longer and I decided to not post it here. But this one is very nice.

Comment: Thanks. I found your code [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Nov/msg00321.html).

Comment: Right...It's hard to believe it has been 4 years already, since that time. This was actually one of the more interesting threads.

Answer (score 3):

In versions 10.2+, `RelationGraph` makes this task an easy one:

```
f = ConnectedComponents @ RelationGraph[IntersectingQ, #]&;
f @ list
```

> {{{a, b}, {b, c}, {c, d}}, {{e, f}, {f, g, h}}}

Answer (score 1):

Appending unnecessary information can really help in this scenario,

```
Most[Rest[# //. {a___, {x__List}, b___} -> {a, x, 
       b} & /@ (FlattenAt[{{1}, ##, {2}} &[(Intersection[{{a, b}, {b, 
           c}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {f, t}, {j, k, l}, {m, n}, {l, m}, {t, 
           k}, {k, h, i}}])],2] 
       //. {q___, s : {a___, b_} | {___, {a___,  b_}, ___}, r___, 
       k : {b_, d___}, t__} -> {q, {s, k}, r, t})]]
```

> {{{a, b}, {b, c}, {c, d}}, {{e, f}, {f, t}, {t, k}, {k, h, i}}, {{l, 
>      m}, {m, n}}, {j, k, l}}

Now it will work for any number of elements in subsets. It can be a good alternate to using graphs.