# Finding neighbors from list

Tags: list-manipulation, sets

Say you are given the following list:

```
list={{3, 2, 1}, {3, 4, 2}, {2, 4, 1}, {1, 4, 3}};
```

Two numbers $x,y$, not necessarily distinct, are neighbors if one of the sub-lists contains both of $x$ and $y$. In more precise mathematical language: let $S=\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\}$ be a collection of $n$ sets, each containing integers between $1$ and $m$. Then $x$ and $y$ are neighbors if $\exists A_i:x,y\in A_i$.

I am looking for an efficient way of finding all the neighbors of each element. That is, let $S'=\{B_1,B_2,\dots,B_m\}$. Then $B_i$ contains all the neighbors of $i$. Note that $B_i$ may be empty if the integer $i$ does not appear in any of the sets in $S$. My current implementation is:

```
Union @@@Function[x, Select[list, MemberQ[#, x] &]] /@ Range@Max@list

(*{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}*)
```

However, it gets fairly slow on large lists. Is there a more efficient way of finding $S'$ in Mathematica?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following. Note I assumed from OP that elements are non-zero integers. This could of course be adapted to other cases with appropriate mapping.

```
getmasks[listarg_] := 
  Reverse[Transpose[
     IntegerDigits[Fold[BitSet[#1, #2] &, 0, #] & /@ listarg, 2, 
      Max[listarg] + 1]]][[Min[listarg] + 1 ;; Max[listarg] + 1]];

getneighbors[listarg_, maskarg_, n_] := 
  Union @@ Pick[listarg, maskarg[[n - Min[listarg] + 1]], 1];
```

Used with some of the examples, and comparing to the memoized routines above, much faster even on the measly netbook I'm lounging with:

```
n = 1000; k = 500; j = 20;
list = DeleteDuplicates /@ RandomInteger[{1, n}, {k, j}];

ClearSystemCache[];
getNeighborsMemo[list, 1] // Timing

ClearSystemCache[];

Timing[masks = getmasks[list];
 getneighbors[list, masks, 1]]
```

Results:

```
{2.636417,{5,9,16,24,57,92,100,113,127,163,184,198,224,249,258,267,268,270,275,282,319,347,350,364,391,432,438,439,462,471,528,534,547,549,552,554,555,558,578,583,599,603,607,609,615,630,639,646,648,677,695,710,711,730,735,740,772,791,797,812,818,825,868,875,890,905,913,932,952,958,972,977,982}}

{0.093601,{1,5,9,16,24,57,92,100,113,127,163,184,198,224,249,258,267,268,270,275,282,319,347,350,364,391,432,438,439,462,471,528,534,547,549,552,554,555,558,578,583,599,603,607,609,615,630,639,646,648,677,695,710,711,730,735,740,772,791,797,812,818,825,868,875,890,905,913,932,952,958,972,977,982}}
```

Note that I include the element as its own 'neighbor', you can of course drop it as required.

With the masks, you can easily do things like quickly get at questions like 'how many lists does element $E1$ appear with element $E2$ as a neighbor?', etc. You'll probably want to add some error checking (no looking for elements out of range, etc.)

Note there is of course a trade-off using this kind of bit-mapping: you're somewhat restricted in cardinality of distinct elements, so you might have to massage/map/index things. Think of the above as a foundation to mold into your specific requirements.

Be sure to look at Mr.Wizard's refactored code below for examples of cleaned-up and enhanced versions of this, and the later part of my answer for the fastest I've come up with.

Here's a way that has no restrictions on element types/sizes/characteristics and is as fast as above for many cases, and not too shabby otherwise. It uses indexed variables and returns all the neighbors in one go:

```
ClearAll[neighbors]
ClearSystemCache[]

testlist = RandomInteger[{1, 5000}, {100, 50}];

Timing[

 (neighbors[#] = {}) & /@ Union[Flatten[testlist]];

 (neighborstgt = 
     Union[#]; (neighbors[#] = Union[neighbors[#], neighborstgt]) & /@
      neighborstgt) & /@ testlist;

 ]

(* time to generate ALL results*)
{0.343202,Null} 

(* show a result *)
neighbors[1]

{1,19,35,48,80,137,182,276,299,308,437,481,537,553,583,620,645,687,696,716,730,817,831,843,855,874,956,1055,1110,1160,1195,1220,1225,1267,1282,1292,1295,1324,1348,1359,1393,1401,1413,1485,1537,1698,1764,1767,1859,1868,1887,1954,2058,2147,2151,2232,2245,2266,2303,2305,2373,2396,2428,2545,2558,2575,2590,2698,2714,2853,2951,2958,2974,2989,3088,3144,3185,3290,3535,3700,3710,3713,3741,3759,3800,3867,3881,3908,4022,4070,4152,4159,4343,4472,4518,4570,4589,4867}
```

Or for random alphabetic 'names', e.g.:

```
ClearAll[neighbors]
ClearSystemCache[]

testlist = Table[RandomSample[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 10], {100}];

Timing[

 (neighbors[#] = {}) & /@ Union[Flatten[testlist]];

 (neighborstgt = 
     Union[#]; (neighbors[#] = Union[neighbors[#], neighborstgt]) & /@
      neighborstgt) & /@ testlist;

 ]

(* show a result *)
neighbors["a"]

{0.078001,Null}
{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z}
```

After fiddling with the idea some more, here's an all-in-one function to do this:

```
getNeighbors[listarg_, eles_: False] := 
  Block[{uniques, map, digits, lu, la},
   If[eles =!= False, 
    Return[Union @@ 
      Select[DeleteDuplicates /@ listarg, MemberQ[#, eles] &]]];
   la = DeleteDuplicates /@ listarg;
   uniques = Union @@ la;
   lu = Length[uniques];
   map = Total[
     la /. Dispatch[Thread[uniques -> 2^Range[0, lu - 1]]], {2}];
   digits = IntegerDigits[map, 2, lu] // Transpose;
   Transpose[{uniques, 
     Pick[uniques, IntegerDigits[#, 2, lu] // Reverse, 
        1] & /@ (BitOr @@ Pick[map, #, 1] & /@ (digits) // 
        Reverse)}]];
```

Passed a list in the form of the OP's query, it returns all of the neighbor information in one go, as a list of lists each with an element as entry 1 and a list of neighbors. This function in not limited to integers:

```
In[366]:= getNeighbors[{{1,2,3},{a,b,v},{2,3,4},{b,c,c,d}}]
Out[366]= {{1,{1,2,3}},{2,{1,2,3,4}},{3,{1,2,3,4}},{4,{2,3,4}},{a,{a,b,v}},{b,{a,b,c,d,v}},{c,{b,c,d}},{d,{b,c,d}},{v,{a,b,v}}}
```

Note that as before I include the element as its own neighbor. If passed the optional second argument of a specific element, it uses a quick method to return the single result set.

Performance wise, this is comparable to the initial version with small cardinality sets, but far outstrips it when the numbers go up, e.g. with the following example of 1000 possible elements in 1000 sublists 
it is far faster than the already fast initial version (the original is outstripped by a factor of 68 in this example):

```
testarg = RandomInteger[{1000, 1999}, {1000, 1000}];

ClearSystemCache[]

{to1, dummy} = Timing[masks = getmasks3[testarg];]
{to2, dummy} = Timing[oldres =  getneighbors[testarg, masks, #] & /@ Union @@ testarg;]

ClearSystemCache[]
{tn1, dummy} = Timing[newres = getNeighbors[testarg];]
tn2 = 0;

(* check results match *)
oldres == newres[[All, 2]]

(* speedup *)
(to1 + to2)/(tn1 + tn2)



{3.822024, Null}

{512.572486, Null}

{7.644049, Null}

True

67.55510
```

N.B.: these timings are from my netbook (goofing with this at a cigar lounge ;-] ), so either should be pretty quick on any 'real' machine.

Some timings as requested by Mr. Wizard. Do note again  - these are on a netbook, so 'real'
machines should be fine with pretty much any of the methods. Also, this is just a quick & dirty timing test, so any pointers on more proper MM benchmarking appreciated.

Result columns are element range, sublist count and size, time for getNeighbors above, neighborsBitmask, and the sow/reap methods respectively, a check that results match, and speed ratios vs getNeighbors for the neighborsBitmask and sow/reap.

```
Scan[
(testarg=RandomInteger[#[[1]],#[[2]]];

ClearSystemCache[];
t1=First[(res1=getNeighbors[testarg];)//Timing];

ClearSystemCache[];
t2=First[(res2=neighborsBitmask[testarg];)//Timing];

ClearSystemCache[];
t3=First[(res3=Sort@Last@Reap[Sow[#,#]&~Scan~testarg,_,{#,Union@@#2}&];)//Timing];

Print[#[[1]],"  ",#[[2]],"  ",Round[t1,.001]," ",Round[t2,.001],"  ",Round[t3,.001],"  ",res1==res2==res3,"  ",t2/t1,"  ",t3/t1];)&,

{{{100,200},{20,30}},{{200,400},{30,40}},{{1,1000},{50,50}},{{1,1000},{100,100}},{{1,1000},{200,100}},{{1,1000},{100,200}},{{1000,3000},{300,300}}}
];

ele. range   sub #/Size  GN      NB      S/R   Check    Ratios

{100,200}     {20,30}   0.016   0.094   0.016  True  6.000    1.000
{200,400}     {30,40}   0.062   0.218   0.047  True  3.5000   0.7500
{1,1000}      {50,50}   0.14    0.671   0.156  True  4.7778   1.1111
{1,1000}     {100,100}  0.296   4.259   1.139  True  14.3684  3.8421
{1,1000}     {200,100}  0.374   8.861   2.371  True  23.6667  6.3333
{1,1000}     {100,200}  0.406  16.084   4.789  True  39.6538  11.8077
{1000,3000}  {300,300}  1.622 113.943  45.334  True  70.2308  27.9423
```

After spending a few more minutes pondering this interesting challenge, yet another alternative that has some advantages. If we know the sublists are 'dense' with neighbors we can beat one of the expensive parts of the problem - the union of sub-results - since we can know something that MM cannot infer - there's a limit to how many distinct neighbors any element can have. By short-circuiting the union, significant time savings can be had:

```
Clear[test,max,list,arg,findN];
(*test={{1,2,3},{2,3,4},{4,5,6}}*)
test=RandomInteger[{1,100},{50000,200}];
test=DeleteDuplicates/@test;


(* Define it *)
(* call with list, element to find neighbors, and cardinality of elements *)

findN[list_,arg_,max_]:=Catch[Fold[If[Length[#]==max,Throw[#1],
      If[MemberQ[#2,arg],Union[##],#1]]&,{},list]];

(* query a singlet *)
ressingle=With[{lst=test,maxx=Length[Union@@test]},findN[lst,4,maxx]];//Timing

(* get all *)
resall=With[{lst=test,maxx=Length[Union@@test]},findN[lst,#,maxx]&/@
           Range[1,maxx]];//Timing

(* get singlet using bitmap *)
resGNSingle=getNeighbors[test,4];//Timing

(*get all using bitmap *)
resGNAll=getNeighbors[test];//Timing

(* compare results *)
ressingle==resGNSingle
resGNAll[[All,2]]==resall

(* findN singlet *)
{4.773631,Null}

(* findN all *)
{16.208504,Null}

(* bitmask singlet *)
{5.803237,Null}

(* bitmask all *)
{42.806674,Null}

(* results comparison check *)
True
True
```

As can be seen, with 50,000 sublists of 200 length each and 100 possible distinct random elements, this is nearly three times faster than the bitmap. Reminder - these timings were again on a netbook - I expect order(s) of magnitude faster when I get back to my workstations.

I'm pondering some other tricks - stay tuned!

Here's a quick-n-dirty method using sparse arrays. It's quite quick, competitive with the bitmap method, sometimes quite a bit faster, other times not, as expected from the trade-offs made for different methods. It is considerably more memory efficient, of course, needing only 5-10% of the overall memory compared to the bitmap method.

```
(* test list *)
test=DeleteDuplicates/@RandomPrime[{10000,100000},{500,100}];

(* make array *)
sa=With[{tmp=Flatten[MapIndexed[Transpose[{#1,ConstantArray[First[#2],Length[#1]]}]&,test],1]},
    SparseArray[tmp->ConstantArray[True,Length[tmp]]]];//Timing


(* get single element's neighbors*)
lookfor=1;

resal=Union@@test[[PropertyValue[sa,AdjacencyLists][[lookfor]]]];//Timing
res2=getNeighbors[test,lookfor];//Timing

(* check singlet results match *)
res2==resal

(* get all *)
resalAll=Transpose[{Union@@test,Union@@@(test[[#]]&/@
DeleteCases[PropertyValue[sa,AdjacencyLists],{}])}];//Timing

res2=getNeighbors[test];//Timing

(* check results match *)
resalAll==res2
Out[900]= {0.140401,Null}
Out[902]= {0.015600,Null}
Out[903]= {0.078001,Null}
Out[904]= True
Out[905]= {1.341609,Null}
Out[906]= {3.619223,Null}
Out[907]= True
```

If non-integer list values are used, the above rules-based mapping to numbers can be used with this.

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed quite fast. Would you care to explain how it works?

Comment: @E.O. Surely: getmasks simply takes the list and for each sublist generates a bitmap where a set bit corresponds to presence of that integer. Taking that list of bitmaps (one per sublist), transposing it gives you a list of bitmaps representing the position(s) of the sublist(s) each integer occupies. Doing this apart = multiple lookups need not redo this. getneighbors takes the desired element as argument and indexes into the bitmap list to get the sublists where the element resides, unioning to complete the task. I've sped it up a bit, will post update after goofing more. Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It'll take some time to digest, but it works quite well :-)

Comment: @E.O. - happy to explain more if needed, ran out of comment! Also, I removed my (probably invalid) assumption that the elements started with 1. Not a good assumption. So, as is, any non-negative integer range should be fine. Again, if you need more clarification feel free to ask.

Comment: Nice method.  Note however that you don't need `BitSet[#1, #2] &` -- merely `BitSet` will do.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: Coming from you, I am honored! Yes, I left those in since I'd been playing with manipulations of the arguments, and you're of course correct they're not needed in the form above.

Comment: I like the update.  I wrote something similar myself, but I used an array to hold bitmask integers for each list element and updated them in a loop with `BitSet`.  I couldn't get the performance to match the Sow/Reap method however.  Your approach with `BitOr` again looks interesting.  I'll see if I can take it farther.  Let me suggest that you do the power operation inside the rule table, e.g.: `Thread[uniques -> 2^Range[0, lu - 1]]`

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: Lol, I made that change already then saw your comment- made a bit of a difference. Like minds... P.S. your sow/reap method below is just plain pretty, a model of conciseness.

Comment: Thanks; `Sow` and `Reap` are some of my favorite functions; although often slower than e.g. `GatherBy` the flexibility they offer is wonderful.  I added my bitmask code to the bottom of my first answer.  It is similar, and yet different.  Perhaps you can draw something useful from it.  I would be curious to see timings for that function (`neighborsBitmask`) and my sow/reap `neighbors` on your machine, compared to your own, if you have time.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Will do - just lit up another cigar, so I'll cut-n-paste your code. Shall I reply in that post with timings on this poor lil' netbook?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Impromptu timings per request added to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the timings.  I now see that your function is optimized for a different class of input, and there it performs very well indeed!  Since mine is faster for other classes I shall try to combine these methods into a superfunction that intelligently selects between the methods, but probably not today.  Happy New Year!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: And felicitations on the new year to you! I look forward to your cleverness here!

Comment: I love seeing how deep you are going with this problem and I look forward to reading your additional methods.  Unfortunately I don't have time to join in, but it doesn't look like you need any help. :-)  By the way, I removed the "community wiki" status that was automatically applied to your post because of the number of edits; I see no reason for you to lose credit (points) for putting in additional effort.

Comment: Cheers! - I wish getting a remote kernel in windows was not such a PITA - I'm goofing with this in my spare time at the cigar shop on an atom-based netbook, and too busy with real work when at workstations. I *really* appreciate your feedback, and any pointers you have to offer are eagerly awaited! This *is* an interesting puzzle, keeps the mind busy!

Answer (score 6):

You seem to have already used a fairly standard and very reasonable approach. An alternate way to do this (I haven't tested it for performance) is to use the graph theory functions. For instance, by creating the adjacency matrix from your list, you can get the neighbours:

```
adj = list /. l : {__Integer} :> Map[# -> 1 &, Permutations[l, {2}]] // 
     Flatten // SparseArray // Normal;
With[{g = AdjacencyGraph@adj}, AdjacencyList[g, #] & /@ VertexList@g] 
(* {{2, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 3}} *)
```

Comment: Is this supposed to run for any sub-lists length? For example for `SeedRandom[42];
n = 1000; k = 300; j = 10;
list = DeleteDuplicates /@ RandomInteger[{1, n}, {k, j}];` I can't reconcile your result with Leonid's or mine.

Comment: @belisarius Thanks. I realize where the mistake is; I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a version of a connectivity problem. Taking the function `listToGraph` from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37249/how-to-split-list-into-disjoint-lists/37251#37251):

```
ClearAll[listToGraph];
listToGraph[list_List] := 
  Graph@Union[
    Sort /@ Flatten[
      Apply[UndirectedEdge, (Partition[#1, 2, 1] &) /@ list, {2}]]];
```

we can then define the function you look for as

```
getNeighbors[list_List, elem_]:= 
   AdjacencyList[listToGraph[Flatten[Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ list, 1]], elem]
```

so that, for example,

```
getNeighbors[list,1]

(* {2, 3, 4} *)
```

If you need to use this for many different elements, it may make sense to memoize the graph constructed for a given list. Here is a version which does that:

```
ClearAll[graph, getNeighborsMemo];
graph[list_List] := graph[list] = 
    listToGraph[Flatten[Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ list, 1]];
getNeighborsMemo[list_List, elem_] := AdjacencyList[graph[list], elem];
```

You use this as before, but now the auxiliary `graph` function will store the resulting graph, for all subsequent calls to `getNeighborsMemo`.

Comment: Lol, I didn't see your answer! I also used the graph theory functions, although my approach is a little different from yours.

Comment: @rm-rf Indeed, similar, but not quite the same implementation. It would be interesting to compare performance, but I can't spend more time on this now.

Answer (score 4):

This is a refactoring of [rasher](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/rasher)'s method because I don't think a bit-mask approach can be beaten.  It is improved especially for the case where elements are not numbered from a low value.  It is not optimized for cases where there is an extreme spread in element values or extended to non-integer elements; those cases would be best handled by replacing elements with sequential natural numbers beforehand.

My code:

```
myMasks[sets_] := Min @ sets /. min_ :>
   {min, IntegerDigits[Fold[BitSet, 0, #] & /@ (sets - min), 2, Max[sets] - min + 1] //
     Transpose // Reverse}

myNeighbors[sets_, {min_, masks_}, n_] := Union @@ Pick[sets, masks[[n - min + 1]], 1]
```

Timing function:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]

timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]
```

Elements starting from 2:

```
SeedRandom[1]
sets = RandomPrime[1000, {200, 4}];

With[{masks = getmasks[sets]}, getneighbors[sets, masks, #] & /@ Union @@ sets] // timeAvg
With[{masks = myMasks[sets]}, myNeighbors[sets, masks, #] & /@ Union @@ sets]   // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.004872
>
> 0.003624
> ```

About one third faster in the base case.  Now with elements starting from 15,013:

```
SeedRandom[1]
sets = RandomPrime[{15000, 17000}, {200, 4}];

With[{masks = getmasks[sets]}, getneighbors[sets, masks, #] & /@ Union @@ sets] // timeAvg
With[{masks = myMasks[sets]}, myNeighbors[sets, masks, #] & /@ Union @@ sets]   // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.01808
>
> 0.00512
> ```

More than 3.5X faster in the target case.

---

Here is a different version also based on bitmasks.  It is not a refactoring of other code, but it falls into the same category so I am including it here.  I could not get the performance to be competitive with the `Sow` and `Reap` method I posted in a separate answer, but I am including it here with the hope that it may inspire someone else in writing a better solution.  Note that the old SparseArray properties trick is used because Pick in v7 is slower; it may be equally fast and cleaner to use `Pick` in later versions.

```
neighborsBitmask[sets : {__List}] :=
  Module[{unique, n, rls, extract, array},
    unique = Union @@ sets;
    n = Length @ unique + 1;
    rls = Dispatch @ Thread[Reverse[unique] -> Range[n - 1]];
    extract = unique[[SparseArray[#] @ "AdjacencyLists"]] &;
    array = ConstantArray[0, n - 1];
    Do[array[[x]] = Fold[BitSet, array[[x]], #], {x, #}] & /@ (sets /. rls);
    {unique, extract @ IntegerDigits[#, 2, n] & /@ Reverse @ array}\[Transpose]
  ]
```

Comment: Nice! This has the same set of tweaks to performance I alluded to in my comment to E.O., and about the same magnitude of performance boost. I shall link here from my answer! +1

Answer (score 4):

Here is a method using `Sow` and `Reap` that I think is clean, flexible, and efficient.  It is especially applicable if you are only interested in the neighbors of a subset of elements, and it natively works with arbitrary list elements.  Here is the basic form:

```
sets = {{3, 7}, {2, 7}, {5, 7}, {3, 2, 6}, {2, 5}, {6, 9, 7}, {3, 6}, {1, 4}}

Sort @ Last @ Reap[Sow[#, #] & ~Scan~ sets, _, {#, Union @@ #2} &] // Column
```

> ```
> {1, {1,4}}
> {2, {2,3,5,6,7}}
> {3, {2,3,6,7}}
> {4, {1,4}}
> {5, {2,5,7}}
> {6, {2,3,6,7,9}}
> {7, {2,3,5,6,7,9}}
> {9, {6,7,9}}
> ```

The same operation on strings:

```
charsets = Map[FromCharacterCode, 96 + sets, {2}];

Sort @ Last @ Reap[Sow[#, #] & ~Scan~ charsets, _, {#, Union @@ #2} &] // Column
```

> ```
> {a, {a,d}}
> {b, {b,c,e,f,g}}
> {c, {b,c,f,g}}
> {d, {a,d}}
> {e, {b,e,g}}
> {f, {b,c,f,g,i}}
> {g, {b,c,e,f,g,i}}
> {i, {f,g,i}}
> ```

Gathering only the neighbors of 1,3,9; the third argument of `Reap` is changed to give only the neighbors since `1`, `3`, `9` can be assumed by position:

```
Last @ Reap[Sow[#, #] & ~Scan~ sets, {1, 3, 9}, Sequence @@ Union @@ #2 &] // Column
```

> ```
> {1,4}
> {2,3,6,7}
> {6,7,9}
> ```

I hope this illustrates the flexibility of this approach.  Here is an attempt to bundle this method in a versatile function:

```
neighbors[sets : {__List}] :=
 Sort @ Last @ Reap[Sow[#, #] & ~Scan~ sets, _, {#, Union @@ #2} &]

neighbors[sets : {__List}, patt_] :=
 Last @ Reap[Sow[#, #] & ~Scan~ sets, patt, Sequence @@ Union @@ #2 &]
```

Usage:

```
neighbors[sets] // Column
neighbors[sets, {1, 3, 9, foo}] // Column
```

> ```
> {1,{1,4}}
> {2,{2,3,5,6,7}}
> {3,{2,3,6,7}}
> {4,{1,4}}
> {5,{2,5,7}}
> {6,{2,3,6,7,9}}
> {7,{2,3,5,6,7,9}}
> {9,{6,7,9}}
>
> {1,4}
> {2,3,6,7}
> {6,7,9}
> {}
> ```

Note that when `foo` was included, which is not present in the set, `{}` is returned.

### Performance

Timing function:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]
```

Timings for all neighbors of a large set, using the function from my other answer:

```
SeedRandom[1]
sets = DeleteDuplicates /@ RandomInteger[9999, {1500, 7}];

neighbors[sets] // timeAvg

With[{masks = myMasks[sets]}, myNeighbors[sets, masks, #] & /@ Union @@ sets] // timeAvg

0.02936

3.759
```

And with counting neighbors for only a small selection of elements:

```
neighbors[sets, RandomPrime[9999, 10]] // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.01312
> ```

It is worth noting that this method may consume a large amount of memory in the case where there is heavy duplication of links, where sublists are long, and when all (or many) neighbors are being counted.  This is because elements are sown repeatedly, then duplicates are removed with `Union` afterward.  A look at what is gathered before the `Union` operation:

```
SeedRandom[1]
sets = DeleteDuplicates /@ RandomInteger[9, {4, 15}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 4, 0, 7, 8, 6, 5}, {1, 3, 2, 6, 0, 4, 5},
>  {5, 3, 0, 2, 9, 1}, {4, 1, 5, 2, 7, 9, 8, 0, 6}}
> ```

```
Reap[Sow[#, #] & ~Scan~ sets][[2]]
```

> {{{1, 4, 0, 7, 8, 6, 5}, {1, 3, 2, 6, 0, 4, 5}, {5, 3, 0, 2, 9, 1},
>   {4, 1, 5, 2, 7, 9, 8, 
>          0, 6}}, {{1, 4, 0, 7, 8, 6, 5}, {1, 3, 2, 6, 0, 4, 5}, {4, 1, 5, 2, 7, 9, 8, 0, 
>          6}}, {{1, 4, 0, 7, 8, 6, 5}, {1, 3, 2, 6, 0, 4, 5}, {5, 3, 0, 2, 9, 1}, {4, 1, 5, 2, 7,
>           9, 8, 0, 6}}, {{1, 4, 0, 7, 8, 6, 5}, {4, 1, 5, 2, 7, 9, 8, 0, 6}}, {{1, 4, 0, 7, 8, 
>          6, 5}, {4, 1, 5, 2, 7, 9, 8, 0, 6}}, {{1, 4, 0, 7, 8, 6, 5}, {1, 3, 2, 6, 0, 4, 5}, {4,
>           1, 5, 2, 7, 9, 8, 0, 6}}, {{1, 4, 0, 7, 8, 6, 5}, {1, 3, 2, 6, 0, 4, 5}, {5, 3, 0, 2, 
>          9, 1}, {4, 1, 5, 2, 7, 9, 8, 0, 6}}, {{1, 3, 2, 6, 0, 4, 5}, {5, 3, 0, 2, 9, 1}}, {{1, 
>          3, 2, 6, 0, 4, 5}, {5, 3, 0, 2, 9, 1}, {4, 1, 5, 2, 7, 9, 8, 0, 6}}, {{5, 3, 0, 2, 9, 
>          1}, {4, 1, 5, 2, 7, 9, 8, 0, 6}}}

Obviously this is memory inefficient.  `Reap` is smart enough to only collect elements for tags which will be used, so this problem is ameliorated by collecting neighbors for a limited number of elements:

```
Reap[Sow[#, #] & ~Scan~ sets, {3, 7}][[2]]
```

> ```
> {{{{1, 3, 2, 6, 0, 4, 5}, {5, 3, 0, 2, 9, 1}}},
>  {{{1, 4, 0, 7, 8, 6, 5}, {4, 1, 5, 2, 7, 9, 8, 0, 6}}}}
> ```

Nevertheless you may want to consider another approach for very long lists.  I am working on another solution using rasher's highly space efficient bitmask format but it is not yet complete.

Comment: This is brilliant! It's a shame I can't accept two answers..

Comment: @E.O. I'm glad you like it. :-)  I added some important notes regarding performance.

Comment: Nice! I've updated my original answer with a pretty quick all-at-once method that also allows arbitrary (i.e. not just integers) elements.

Comment: @rasher Great; let me take a look.

Comment: Now I understand `Reap` and `Sow` tag structure and `Reap` 3th and 4th argument.. tks

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[42];
list = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, {30, 3}];
Function[{elem}, {elem, Union @@ Select[list, MemberQ[#, elem] &]}][#] & /@ (Union @@ list)
```

Or

```
SeedRandom[42];
list = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, {30, 3}];
s = Function[{elem}, {elem, Union @@ (Pick[list, #] &@(MemberQ[#, elem] & /@ list))}][#] & /@ 
                                                                                    (Union @@ list)
```

**Edit**

I like this one, but it's way slower:

```
SeedRandom[42];
list = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, {30, 3}];
df[x_, y_] := If[Cases[list, {___, x, ___, y, ___} | {___, y, ___, x, ___}] != {}, 1, 2, 2]
f = Nearest[Union @@ list, DistanceFunction -> (df[#1, #2] &)]
{#, f@#} & /@ (Union @@ list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not so compact but works OK on large input :

```
n = 4; list = {{3, 2, 1}, {3, 4, 2}, {2, 4, 1}, {1, 4, 3}};

(* generate all pairs of neighbours implied by list *)
pairs = Flatten[Permutations[#, {2}] & /@ list, 1];
(* pairs contains many duplicates but cleaning it up takes longer *)
s = ConstantArray[{}, n];
While[pairs != {},
  p = First@pairs;
  AppendTo[s[[First@p]], Last@p];
  AppendTo[s[[Last@p]], First@p];
  pairs = Rest[pairs];];
(* cleanup *)
Sort /@ DeleteDuplicates /@ s
```

For a longer input:

```
n = 20; k = 30; j = 3;
list = DeleteDuplicates /@ RandomInteger[{1, n}, {k, j}];
(* 0.003493 sec *)
```

and

```
n = 1000; k = 300; j = 10;
list = DeleteDuplicates /@ RandomInteger[{1, n}, {k, j}];
(* 2.618397 sec *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another..

```
({#[[1, 1]], Union@Flatten@Take[#, All, {2}]}) & /@ 
     GatherBy[
      Flatten[{#, Reverse@#} & /@ 
           Union@Flatten[Sort /@ Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ list, 1], 1], #[[1]] &]
```

Answer (score 1):

Such a nice challenge, thought I'd contribute, even though I'm a bit late:

Borrowing Mr.Wizard's data...

```
sets={{"c","g"},{"b","g"},{"e","g"},{"c","b","f"},{"b","e"},{"f","i","g"},{"c","f"},{"a","d"}};
```

---

**Edit**: I find this variant very straightforward and easy to understand (although this is of course a matter of judgment). However, it is far less efficient than Mr.Wizard's approach.

### Code

```
elements=Union@@sets;
p[el_]:= p[el]={el,Position[sets,el][[All,1]]}
neighbors2[el_]:={el,Union@@Extract[sets,List/@p[el][[2]]]}
```

---

### Analysis

**Step 1: Get the elements**

```
elements
```

> {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "i"}

---

**Step 2: Find the sets each element belongs to**

`p[element]` finds all the sets an element is a member of.  Memoization is used to eliminate redundant calculations of `p`.

*Which sets is an element a member of?*

```
p/@elements
```

> {{"a", {8}}, {"b", {2, 4, 5}}, {"c", {1, 4, 7}}, {"d", {8}}, {"e", {3,
>       5}}, {"f", {4, 6, 7}}, {"g", {1, 2, 3, 6}}, {"i", {6}}}

---

**Step 3: Find the neighbors of each element**

`neighbors[element]` returns `element`'s neighbors by getting all of the elements in the sets to which `element` belongs.

*Who are the neighbors of* `f`?

```
neighbors["f"]
```

> {"f", {"b", "c", "f", "g", "i"}}

Who are the neighbors of each element?

```
neighbors/@elements//Column
```

[image: neighbors]

Comment: I get errors when I try to run this; e.g. `Part::partw: Part 2 of {8} does not exist. >>`

Comment: Ditto: "Intersection::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in 2\[Intersection]2", returns empty sets. Neat idea though, I'm guessing a typo.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I fixed it (in a prior edit) but then found a more direct way to solve the problem, using the same general logic. See above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion, storing in `DownValues`:

```
ClearAll@getNeighbors
getNeighbors[list_]:=Module[{addPair,id,elements},

    elements=DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@list;
    Scan[(id[#]={})&,elements];
    addPair[a_,b_]:=id[a]=DeleteDuplicates@Join[id[a],{b}];
    Scan[addPair@@@Permutations[#,{2}]&,list];
    SortBy[{#,id@#}&/@elements,First]
]

list={{1,4},{9,11,4},{8,9,7},{5,11,12},{2,7,23},{22}};
getNeighbors[list]//Column
```

> ```
> {1,{4}}
> {2,{7,23}}
> {4,{1,9,11}}
> {5,{11,12}}
> {7,{2,8,9,23}}
> {8,{7,9}}
> {9,{4,7,8,11}}
> {11,{4,5,9,12}}
> {12,{5,11}}
> {22,{}}
> {23,{2,7}}
> ```

### Using Association

Playing with `Association`, I tried this (very inefficient) code:

```
ClearAll@getNeighborsAss
getNeighborsAss[list_]:=Module[{addPair,ass},

    ass=Association[#-> {}&/@DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@list];
    addPair[a_,b_]:=ass=Combine[{ass,<|a-> {b}|>},Join@@##&];
    Scan[addPair@@@Permutations[#,{2}]&,list];
    ass
]

list={{1,4},{9,11,4},{8,9,7},{5,11,12},{2,7,23},{22}};
getNeighborsAss[list]
```

> ```
> <|1 -> {4}, 4 -> {1, 9, 11}, 9 -> {11, 4, 8, 7}, 11 -> {9, 4, 5, 12}, 
>  8 -> {9, 7}, 7 -> {8, 9, 2, 23}, 5 -> {11, 12}, 12 -> {5, 11}, 
>  2 -> {7, 23}, 23 -> {2, 7}, 22 -> {}|>
> ```

Comment: I made this `Association` code using Version 10 (beta). I think that it's no problem because RPi has it. If some Wolfram people disagree, I remove it.