# Sorting a Collection of Lists by Comparing Different Parts

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, programming, sorting

I am looking for a way to use `Sort[]` to sort a collection of lists by comparing different parts of these lists. For example, sorting by comparing the second part of one list with the first part of another.

More specifically, given the list

```
list={{1, 4}, {2, 7}, {4, 6}, {5, 2}, {6, 5}, {7, 1}}
```

I would like to use `Sort[]` to sort `list` such that `list[[1,2]]` equals `list[[2,1]]`, `list[[2,2]]` equals `list[[3,1]]`, etc. giving output

```
{{1, 4}, {4, 6}, {6, 5}, {5, 2}, {2, 7}, {7, 1}}
```

---

I tried

```
Sort[list, (#1[[2]] == #2[[1]]) &]
```

but the output is

```
{{2, 7}, {7, 1}, {6, 5}, {5, 2}, {1, 4}, {4, 6}}
```

Repeatedly applying this sort function using `Nest` or `FixedPoint` did not give the output I wanted either.

Notice this problem is more general, as replacing `==` with `<` or `>` in my sort function does not sort the way one would expect either.

Though I know of ways to do this, I am looking for a nice, fast way, preferably using `Sort`.

Comment: Does this work? `Reverse@Partition[Sort[list, (#1[[2]] == #2[[1]]) &], 2]~Flatten~1`

Comment: Alternatively, I think this would work? `Partition[FindHamiltonianPath[DirectedEdge @@@ list], 2, 1, 1]`. Let me know if these suggestions work for you generally (i.e. try it on more complicated examples), and if so, I can write an answer.

Comment: @march No, your first function does not. It happens to work for the example I gave above, but given `list={{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {3, 1}, {5, 7}, {6, 3}, {7, 6}}` your function outputs `{{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {7, 6}, {3, 1}, {6, 3}, {5, 7}}` when it should give `{{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {5, 7}, {7, 6}, {6, 3}, {3, 1}}`.

Comment: Yeah, it was definitely a kluge. I'm willing to bet that the second one should work in general, though, and if it *doesn't*, then I suspect the problem is ill-posed (i.e. there is more than one solution to your problem). Let me know!

Comment: Here's a better version of the 2nd one: `List @@@ First@FindHamiltonianCycle[UndirectedEdge @@@ list]`.

Comment: duplicate? : [Rearranging a List](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42219/125)

Comment: Are the ends supposed to be connected? I.e., do you want to have `list[[-1, 2]] === list[[1, 1]]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lst1 = {{1, 4}, {2, 7}, {4, 6}, {5, 2}, {6, 5}, {7, 1}};
lst2 = {{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {3, 1}, {5, 7}, {6, 3}, {7, 6}};
```

**1.** An alternative method using [`FindCycle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindCycle.html) and [`RelationGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html):

```
ClearAll[findCycl1]
findCycl1 =  FindCycle[RelationGraph[#[[2]] == #2[[1]] &, # ]][[1, ;; , 1]] &;

findCycl1 /@ {lst1, lst2}
```

> {{{1, 4}, {4, 6}, {6, 5}, {5, 2}, {2, 7}, {7, 1}},
>    {{1, 2}, {2, 
>          5}, {5, 7}, {7, 6}, {6, 3}, {3, 1}}}

**2.** Recursive replacement with [`FixedPoint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPoint.html):

```
ClearAll[step, findCycl2]
step[p : {__, {}}] := p
step[{p1___, {a_, b_}, {d___, {b_, c_}, e___}}] := {p1, {a, b}, {b, c}, {d, e}}
findCycl2 = Most @ FixedPoint[step, {First @ #, Rest @ #}] &;


findCycl2 /@ {lst1, lst2}
```

> {{{1, 4}, {4, 6}, {6, 5}, {5, 2}, {2, 7}, {7, 1}},
>    {{1, 2}, {2, 
>          5}, {5, 7}, {7, 6}, {6, 3}, {3, 1}}}

**3.** Using `step` with [`NestWhile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhile.html)

```
ClearAll[findCycl3]
findCycl3 = Most @ NestWhile[step, {First@#, Rest@#}, Last[#] != {} &] &;
findCycl3 /@ {lst1, lst2}
```

> {{{1, 4}, {4, 6}, {6, 5}, {5, 2}, {2, 7}, {7, 1}},
>    {{1, 2}, {2, 
>          5}, {5, 7}, {7, 6}, {6, 3}, {3, 1}}}

Comment: I like the `FixedPoint[]` solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using march's general idea to treat the pairs as a list of graph edges:

```
List @@@ First[FindCycle[Rule @@@ {{1, 4}, {2, 7}, {4, 6}, {5, 2}, {6, 5}, {7, 1}}]]
   {{1, 4}, {4, 6}, {6, 5}, {5, 2}, {2, 7}, {7, 1}}

List @@@ First[FindCycle[Rule @@@ {{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {3, 1}, {5, 7}, {6, 3}, {7, 6}}]]
   {{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {5, 7}, {7, 6}, {6, 3}, {3, 1}}
```